# iText - BLAZOR - How to nest tables with full width

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, itext, blazor

i'm using iText to generate a PDF. The code is: `        public async Task<byte[]> GeneratePdf(List<ValidStaffMemberDTO> staffMemberCalas)
{

```
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
        var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        var document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        var header = new Paragraph("Trabajadores")
            .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .SetFontSize(20);

        var table = new Table(new[] { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f }).UseAllAvailableWidth();

        var cell11 = new Cell(1, 1)
            .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GRAY)
            .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .Add(new Paragraph("Nombre"));
        var cell12 = new Cell(1, 1)
            .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GRAY)
            .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .Add(new Paragraph("Categoría"));
        var cell13 = new Cell(1, 1)
            .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GRAY)
            .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .Add(new Paragraph("Código"));
        var cell14 = new Cell(1, 1)
            .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GRAY)
            .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
            .Add(new Paragraph("Usuario R+"));

        table.AddCell(cell11);
        table.AddCell(cell12);
        table.AddCell(cell13);
        table.AddCell(cell14);

        try
        {

            foreach (var staffMember in staffMemberCalas)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(staffMember.StaffMember.Name ?? string.Empty)));

                if (staffMember.StaffMember.Category != null)
                    table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(staffMember.StaffMember.Category.Description ?? string.Empty)));
                else
                    table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(string.Empty)));

                table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(staffMember.StaffMemberCalasCode ?? string.Empty)));
                table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(staffMember.UserWithWorkGroup.FirstOrDefault() == null ? string.Empty : $"{staffMember.UserWithWorkGroup.FirstOrDefault().User.NameAndSurnames}")));


                if (staffMember.UserWithWorkGroup[0] != null)
                {

                    //INNER TABLE

                    Table innertable = new Table(new[] { 1f, 1f }).UseAllAvailableWidth();

                    var cell21 = new Cell(1, 1)
                   .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GRAY)
                   .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                   .Add(new Paragraph("Nombre grupo trabajo"));
                    var cell22 = new Cell(1, 1)
                        .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GRAY)
                        .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                        .Add(new Paragraph("Activo"));

                    innertable.AddCell(cell21);
                    innertable.AddCell(cell22);


                    foreach (var userWithWorkGroup in staffMember.UserWithWorkGroup)
                    {
                        if (userWithWorkGroup != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var wg in userWithWorkGroup.WorkGroup)
                            {
                                innertable.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(wg.Name ?? string.Empty)));
                                innertable.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(wg.IsInactive ? "Baja" : "Alta")));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            innertable.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(string.Empty)));
                            innertable.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(string.Empty)));
                        }

                    }

                    table.AddCell(innertable);
                    table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 3).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(new Paragraph(string.Empty)));

                }

            }


            document.Add(header);
            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            pdfWriter.Flush();
            pdfWriter.Close();
            memoryStream.Flush();
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Basically the scenario is one List, and a nested list property of that first list, that can exist or not.

And this generates the image linked. So, how can use 4 columns the nested tabled instead only 1 cell? i wan't to use 4 cells so it can fills all the width. In the end, i just want to remove the vertical separator line...

Thanks and apologizes for my bad english :(

[PDF generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP80K.png)

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5afEV.png)

I tryed to create a cell with all the width (4 cells). But that did not work.